# Azure Devops Service TFVC repos - cost

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, tfvc

The company I work for has azure dev ops services and have the code in repos using TFVC instead of git.  Is there any additional cost involved in managing the code in TFVC, or is the cost covered by the license for azure devops services ?

Comment: Cost covered by the license for Azure DevOps services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is cost differential between using TFVC and git as your source control. Licensing is primarily based on per user. For open source and teams of 5 or less, it's free. After 5, each additional user has cost. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/azure-devops-services/?nav=min for more information.